# I want to achieve the same result but from another way... another logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    ASE.event_time, ASE.State, ASE.Agent_id,
    CASE WHEN ASE.state = 'LOGIN' THEN event_time else b.login_time END AS Login_time
    FROM
    AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS As ASE
    LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.agent_id,
    event_time login_time,
    ISNULL(LEAD(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY A.AGENT_ID ORDER BY event_time ), b.logout_DATE) next_login_time
    FROM
    AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
    agent_id,
    event_time logout_date,
    ISNULL( LEAD(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY AGENT_ID ORDER BY event_time), A.event_time) last_logout
    FROM
    AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A
    WHERE 
    agent_id = 4037
    and event_time BETWEEN '2020-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-12 23:59:59'
    AND state = 'LOGOUT')B
    
    ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id 
    AND b.last_logout = b.logout_date
    WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2020-11-12 00:00:00' and '2020-11-12 23:59:59'
    and a.agent_id = 4037
    AND state = 'LOGIN') B
    ON
    ASE.agent_id = b.agent_id 
    AND ASE.event_time > b.login_time 
    and ASE.event_time <= b.next_login_time
    WHERE ASE.event_time BETWEEN '2020-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-12 23:59:59'
    and ASE.agent_id = 4037
    ORDER BY ASE.agent_id,ASE.event_time
```

This code creates a new column (Login_Time) of date time against each trigger 
Triggers are

1. LOGIN
2. NOT_READY
3. READY
4. BUSY
5. INTERRUPTED
6. UNKNOWN
7. LOGOUT

Above mentioned are the triggers. A session will start from "Login" trigger & will end on "Logout" Trigger. I am trying to create a new column "Login_Time" which should display login time of session in front of each trigger. When the agent logout & then login again, "Login" trigger will get fired & now the "Login_Time" column should display the new Login time stamp.

With the help of this new column "Login_Time", I will be able to identify that which trigger was fired in which session

[image: Result Set of the above query]

Comment: If someone needs the script of the table, that can also be provided

Comment: Yes I want the queried information. The pic attached represent the result set, which the above query returns. I am looking to have the idea that how same result set can be obtained but from a different sql logic.
For Example in the above query LEAD function is used, now i am trying to think of a different way to get the same result set but without using LEAD Function.

Comment: "...from a different SQL logic" doesn't make sense to me? Why do you want different logic? What sort of different logic?

Comment: This sounds like a best practice question to me instead of broken code. Something that does not fit for SO. Maybe somewhere like [codereview.se] would be more suited for this question?